# user inheritance in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-registration

I saw a couple of ways extending user information of users and decided to adopt the model inheritance method.

for instance, I have :

```
class Parent(User):
    contact_means = models.IntegerField()
    is_staff = False 
    objects = userManager()
```

Now it is done, I've downloaded django_registration to help me out with sending emails to new users. The thing is, instead of using registration forms to register new user, I want to to invoke the email sending/acitvation capability of django_registration. So my workflow is:

```
1. add new Parent object in admin page.
2. send email
```

My problem is, the django-registration creates a new registration profile together with a new user in the user table. how do I tweak this such that I am able to add the user entry into the custom user table.

I have tried to create a

> `modelAdmin`

and alter the save_model method to launch the create_inactive_user from django_registration, however I do not how to save the user object generated from django_registration into my Parent table when I have using model inheritance and I do not have a Foreign key attribute in my parent model.

Comment: Yes you do have an implicit foreign key to user in Parent, created by the model inheritance, will be called user_ptr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably something like:

```
p = Parent()
p.user_ptr = user
p.contact_means = ...
p.save()
```

(Django creates the foreign key for you when doing model inheritance, plus the attribute ending in _ptr)

Comment: No. Django's ORM uses metaprogramming to create attributes in your Python classes based on your model's fields and relations. It uses certain conventions (by appending e.g. _set, _ptr to the field name) for these additional attributes.

Comment: Not works for me, this would overwrite all the data of `user` to Null or default.